# How to download files through https in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a webapp where files were uploaded. You can login to the site with a valid account and then download those files. I am currently automating the whole framework using Ruby, Capybara and Selenium Webdriver, but I cannot automate the process of downloading files.

So far I tried using Selenium (which didn't work), also I used the Ruby library `open-uri`:

```
def downloadFile(path)
  open('testing.docx', 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(path).read
  end
  download = open(path)
  IO.copy_stream(download, File.expand_path("resources\\downloads"))
end
```

Where `path` is the href of the link to the file, but at first I got the following error:

> openssl::ssl::sslerror: ssl_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=sslv3 read server certificate b: certificate verify failed

In order to avoid it I used the following code:

> OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

But in the end, I could not download the file.

At this point I think I should load a certificate or maybe retrieve login token from cookies or else where, but I could not figure it out where exactly.

Is there a way to download files from a page which requires login?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium, you should download files through the browser by clicking corresponding links and buttons.

Here is described how to set up browser downloads.

https://watirwebdriver.com/browser-downloads/

Comment: watirwebdriver.com is expired, is there any other sources? I am unable to find anything... Googling for 4 hours so far...

Comment: @NodirNasirov I hope it will come up again. Meanwhile, try this https://watir.com/examples/

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the uri from "https" to "http" like this:

```
path = path.sub("https","http")
```